# relations between equinumerosity and infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given: $A\cap B$ has a one-to-one correspondence to $A$.

If $A\cup B \neq A,$ then is it true then that $B$ must then be an infinite set?

I managed to prove that A is an infinite set in the case of A∪B≠B but could not apply the same logic to the case above.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not necessarily: consider $A= \{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $B =  \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$; $B$ is not infinite.

Comment: A set is infinite iff it is equinumerous with its proper subset.

Comment: szw1710 thats how I proved the first case, I proved that A∩B was a proper subset of A and equinumerousity to A was given. But I can't apply the same in this case since I don't have equinumerousity given with B.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you have provided a counter example which suffices to disprove the claim. if you mark it as an answer I will select it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we are given two sets: $A$ and $B$, such that $A\cap B$ is in one-to-one correspondence with A.

Let $A= \{1, 2\},$ $\;B=\{1,2,3, 4\}.\;$  Then  $A\cap B = \{1, 2\}=A$ and we see that  $A$ is in one-to-one correspondence $A\cap B$.

Then, we have $A\cup B = \{1, 2, 3, 4\} =  B \neq A$.  And $B$ ***is finite.***

So the implication you write at the top of your post is incorrect, since we have found $A, B$ such that the hypotheses are all true, but the conclusion (that B must therefore be infinite) is false.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general: consider $A = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $B = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$.

We have that $A \cap B=A$ is in one-to-one correspondence to $A$ but $B$ is not infinite.

What we need is that $A \cap B$ must be a *proper* subset of $A$ that is in one-to-one correspondence to $A$.

In this case, by definition of *finite* set, $A$ is not finite.

Of course, the same apply with $B$: if $A \cap B$ is a proper subset of $B$ that is equipotent with $B$, then $B$ is *infinite*.

---

We may consider the case: $A= \mathbb N$ and $B= \{n \mid n \in \mathbb N \text { and } n \text { is even } \}$.

In this case $A \cap B = B \subsetneq A$; $A \cap B$ is equipotent with both $A$ and $B$ and thus both are infinite.

But in this case: $A \cup B = A \ne B$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I up voted your answer. As stated in my comment I would have selected it as an answer as well but it looks like someone has beaten you to it. Thanks again for your help.